# Is it possible to make a template that can only take specific types?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I was wondering if it was possible for a template (or any other tool you might recommend)to only take a type from a list of specific types (like an enum, but with already existing types).
More specifically, if I have 3 classes, class A, class B and class C, and I'd like a function to be able to take any of those three classes as argument (but no other class than the 3), what should I do ?
Should I use a template (if so how should I use it), or are there other tools for me to use ?

Comment: If it's only 3 then function overloading *might* be a better choice

Comment: try [static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: What horrible thing happens if a class, not one of those 3, worked?  Are we talking a sign of the apocalypse?  Or just you figure it would be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

The options that comes to mind for me are SFINAE, static_assert or overloading. What option is best would depend on the function itself.

SFINAE method

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<A, T>::value ||
    std::is_same<B, T>::value ||
    std::is_same<C, T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T t) {
    // ...
}
```

Static assert

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<A, T>::value ||
        std::is_same<A, T>::value ||
        std::is_same<A, T>::value, "Must pass A, B or C");
    // ...
}
```

Overloading

```
void foo(A a) {
    // ...
}

void foo(B a) {
    // ...
}

void foo(C a) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Why do you only want this to work for three `class`es?  In general, it's a better idea to keep your interfaces open and support any types that come along (within reason, of course).
2. If you're sure you want to do this, then a custom type trait and `enable_if` is probably the best route.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <type_traits>

   template <typename T>
   struct is_my_special_type;

   template <>
   struct is_my_special_type<int> {
       static const bool value = true;
   };

   template <>
   struct is_my_special_type<long> {
       static const bool value = true;
   };

   template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<is_my_special_type<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
   void foo(T val) {
       std::cout << val << '\n';
   }

   int main() {
       foo(10);
       foo(10l);
       foo(10.0);  // won't compile unless you comment this line out
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   You can add types through template specialization of `my_special_type`.  You could also use `static_assert` instead of `enable_if` if you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Constraining template parameters to only be of specific types, or types meeting certain requirements, is part of what [**C++ Concepts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) is about.

Concepts are a future feature of the C++ language (coming to the official standard perhaps in C++20), which have been specified in a TS (technical specification) - making them a possible extension for compilers to implement if they wish.

For a short introduction-that's-not-intended-as-such, watch:

[What makes a good C++ concept?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_g65LUXpBI) / Bjarne Stroustrup, CppCon 2016